# Не запускается ./hello: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5: version `Qt_5.12' not found (required by ./hello)

Tags: c++, qt

```
#include <QtWidgets>                                                  
                                                                      
int main(int argc, char** argv)                                       
{                                                                     
  QApplication app(argc, argv);                                       
  QLabel lbl("Hello, World !");                                       
  lbl.show();                                                         
  return app.exec();                                                  
}
```

Debian-based OS. Qt_5.12.10. Qt Creator пока не использую, пишу в emacs. Запустил в командной строке g++ для компиляции вышеобозначенного кода, подсунув ему заголовочники и динамические библиотеки (сделал alias). Компилятор отработал, но ./hello не запускается (./hello: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5: version `Qt_5.12' not found (required by ./hello)). Что это? Почему ему требуется версия 5.12?

```
alias g++_qt='g++ -Wall -g -fPIC -I/home/UserName/Qt5.12.10/5.12.10/gcc_64/include/{"",Qt{Core,Gui,Widgets}} -L/home/UserName/Qt5.12.10/5.12.10/gcc_64/lib/ -lQt5{Core,Gui,Widgets}'
```

Comment: как именно собираешь, как именно «подсунув заголовочники и динамические библиотеки» и что значит «сделал alias»? ну и заодно, откуда у тебя кьют и как он установлен?

Comment: $ g++_qt hello.cpp -o hello

Comment: Потому что вы сами линкуете версию 5.12, которая не доступна для динамической загрузки при старте приложения.

Comment: @user7860670, можно чуть подробней? Файл libQt5Core.so -- символьная ссылка на libQt5Core.so.5.12.10

Comment: 5.12.10  и 5.12  -- это разные версии?

Comment: Кьют с сайта скачал, по-моему. Потому что в репах только 4-й был, может ошибаюсь.

Comment: так Qt установлен, или просто "скачан и распакован вручную"?

Comment: @GenaChernikov, смотри: ты линкуешь со своими библиотеками скачанными с сайта, а при запускаешь с системными... или запускай со своими: `LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/home/UserName/Qt5.12.10/5.12.10/gcc_64/lib/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH" ./hello` (`LD_LIBRARY_PATH` можно и просто экспортировать), или установи кьют (включая `*-dev` пакеты) из репов (он там есть и даже у тебя установлен) и используй его... также, в качестве альтернативы, можешь линковать свой бинарник, указывая полные пути к библиотекам в ключе `-l`: `gcc ... -l/home/UserName/Qt5.12.10/5.12.10/gcc_64/lib/libQt5{Core,Gui,Widgets}.so'`.

Comment: если нет какой-либо особой необходимости, я бы советовал использовать кьют из реп...

Comment: @Fat-Zer  Да, все верно, спасибо. Снес скачанный кьют с помощью скрипта Maintenance Tool, установил *-dev-пакеты (qt5 уже стоял, да).